# pyspark create column of date from tweets timestamp

Tags: datetime, pyspark

Im working on tweet dataframe and i want to use the timestamp column differentiate the tweets by date, however datetime conversion from timestamp does not work on a column, is there any way to do that conversion? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

datediff(Column end, Column start)
Returns the number of days from start to end.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F    
df = df.withColumn(F.datediff(F.(end_col), F.(start_col)))
```

In case you are trying to get date use below 
using date_format

```
>>> df.select(date_format(col('ts'),"yyyy-MM-dd").alias('ts').cast("date")).show(10,False)
```

or using to_date

```
>>> df.select(to_date(col('ts')).alias('ts').cast("date")).show(10,False)
```

or Using from_unixtime and unix_timestamp functions:

```
>>> df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col('ts'),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"),"yyyy-MM-dd").alias("ts").cast("date")).show(10,False)
```

Comment: i am not trying to find the maximum difference between dates, i am trying to get a date for each row based on the timestamp so that i could perform date based queries afterwards.

Comment: can you please post some of the sample data here ?

Comment: updated the code .. please see if you are looking for something like this